# why is Twitter Stream API results vs Twitter Search API are different?

Tags: python, twitterapi-python

I wrote a tweet dataset maker using Twitter stream API, the plan is to stream on a specific hashtag and save its live tweets in a DB. and after a period of time using Search API to fetch updated data and store them on top of streamed data.

here is the problem.

Let's say when I stream a hashtag for 2 days, I would get a list of 1000 tweets saved in my DB, after 2 days if I search the exact period of time with the same hashtag I would get 4000 tweets! so it's much more than what I got in Stream API. does that mean Stream API is not giving me all the tweets in that period of running?